# What are the resons for the run time error 5631? How to fix this problem?

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I'm trying to implement a routine that fills out a Word-template with data saved on a SQL-Server. I've got the error "5631" *[Word could not merge the main document with the data source because data records were empty or no data records matched your query options"]* points at ".Execution pause:=false"

I really couldn't figure out the reason for this Problem. Thank you for any help.

Here is the code snippet:

```
Set wrdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
        With wrdApp
            Set wrdDoc = .Documents.Add(sTemplate, False)
            With wrdDoc.MailMerge
                .MainDocumentType = wdFormLetters
                .OpenDataSource Name:="d:\connect.odc" _
                    , ConfirmConversions:=False _
                    , ReadOnly:=False _
                    , LinkToSource:=False _
                    , AddToRecentFiles:=False _
                    , Revert:=False _
                    , Format:=wdOpenFormatAuto _
                    , Connection:=EPLconnectWord(bAcc) _
                    , SQLStatement:="SELECT * FROM [" & sTable & "] WHERE [UserID] = " & lUserID _
                    , SQLStatement1:="" _
                    , SubType:=wdMergeSubTypeOther

                If .State = wdMainAndSourceAndHeader Or .State = wdMainAndDataSource Then
                    .ViewMailMergeFieldCodes = False
                End If
                .Destination = wdSendToNewDocument
                .SuppressBlankLines = True
                With .DataSource
                    .FirstRecord = wdDefaultFirstRecord
                    .LastRecord = wdDefaultLastRecord
                End With
                .Execute Pause:=False
                wrdDoc.ActiveWindow.View.ShowFieldCodes = False
                wrdDoc.Close wdDoNotSaveChanges
            End With ' wrdDoc.MailMerge
```

Comment: hi, does your variable **lUserID** have a value ? and the variable its **lUserID** or just **UserID**. good luck